# UI design for screen which has number of data entry textFields

Tags: iphone

my app is an e-commerce application. During the checkout process, I have "recipient" and "credit card" screens. In the recipient screen, there are number of fields for address entry, which makes it very clumsy. Same in the case of the credit card screen, where the user is asked to enter their credit card info and billing address.

Can anyone suggest how to design these two pages?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to design a data entry screen on the iPhone is to:

1) Always have the keyboard present. If you have to scroll the entry fields, then scroll the entry fields.

2) Only enter data once, then allow the user to save the data for the next launch or purchase.  If you're saving credit card information make sure you use encryption, although encryption will require a little extra work.

3) You may not want to use encryption for the credit card information, in that case, see tip # 1). Or use the Keychain in the iphone to store secure data.